# IntelliJ won't let me compile code with a NullPointerException

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm writing some code in Kotlin that throws a NullPointerException *on purpose* (don't matter why).

Problem is IntelliJ won't even let me compile it.

```
var x: MyClass? = MyClass()
x = null
var y = x!!.myProperty
```

I tried using `@Suppress("ALWAYS_NULL", "UNREACHABLE_CODE")` inline and on the whole file `@file:Suppress("ALWAYS_NULL", "UNREACHABLE_CODE")` but it still won't let me compile it.

How to compile it?

**EDIT:**

Actually I thought it was IntelliJ but even trying to compile it manually won't work. I guess the compiler is smarter than me and using `!!` isn't so assertive as I thought it would be.

Comment: What error are you getting when trying to compile this?

Comment: an Unresolved reference error. It works if I change the `!!` to `?` but of course that's not what I want, IntelliJ picks up the fact that the variable is null, even if I'm using the non-null asserted `!!`, the IDE still knows I'm cheating. Is there a way to just tell the IDE to let me do whatever I want?

Comment: It's weird because this is compiling for me fine, just with a warning. What version of compiler are you using? And is the Unresolved reference error happening on `y` or `x`?

Comment: `Kotlin version 1.6.10-release-923 (JRE 11.0.11+9)`, the error is happening on `x`

Comment: Do you still get an compiler error if you don't reference `myProperty`? Like var `y = x!!`?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do not. I can say `y: MyClass = x!!` without getting the compilation error. mmh.. I'm so confused now

Comment: I suspect the problem is more about how `myProperty` is defined in `MyClass` than the `!!`. Could you share the code for `MyClass`?

Comment: As simple as you would imagine it: `class MyClass {val myProperty = "my property"}` it was just to try it out

Comment: I'm assuming you've already rejected the simple, obvious solution of `throw NullPointerException()`…?

Comment: Yes, that was not how I intended to do it. I'm new to Kotlin and while learning, one thing leads to another and suddenly I'm stuck trying to understand the weirdest things.. I'm sure you know what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like this.

```
private var Nothing.myProperty: String
    get() = myProperty
    set(value){
        myProperty = "null"
    }

fun main() {
   var x: MyClass? = MyClass()
   var y = x!!.myProperty
}

class MyClass {

    var myProperty: String? = null

}
```

Compiling without problem.
I think if class is null then is better to make if...else checker But more problems bring if property in class somehow will be null

Comment: Wow, this works indeed.. I get my NullPointerException just like I wanted! Although I don't understand why this compiles?

Comment: Maybe, if you need to downgrade kotlin. Becouse, if set breakpoint in nullpointerexception, then in Intrinsics.java it point to  @SinceKotlin(version = "1.4")
    public static void throwJavaNpe() {
        throw sanitizeStackTrace(new NullPointerException());
    }

Comment: Since extensions do not actually insert members into classes, there's no efficient way for an extension property to have a backing field. This is why initializers are not allowed for extension properties. Their behavior can only be defined by explicitly providing getters/setters. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#companion-object-extensions

Comment: What I don't understand is why this line `Nothing.myProperty: String` is making the line `x!!.myProperty` compile.. I don't get what does the backing field have to do with this

Comment: Sorry, i can only point to official docs (i am poor in theory) - Nothing has no instances. You can use Nothing to represent "a value that never exists": for example, if a function has the return type of Nothing, it means that it never returns (always throws an exception). https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html

Comment: I can change `Nothing` with anything else, and it would still compile. If I write `MyClass.myProperty: String` the line `x!!.myProperty` compiles. I really can't wrap my head around it